# Send ISO8583 Message to WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, wso2, iso8583, wso2-esb

I am trying to send ISO 8583 message to WSO2 ESB after implementing the inbound endpoint in the official WSO2 documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Inbound+Operations

I created the following artifacts:

ISO8583 Inbound Endpoint:

```
<inboundEndpoint
    class="org.wso2.carbon.inbound.iso8583.listening.ISO8583MessageConsumer"
    name="iso8583" onError="fault" sequence="request" suspend="false">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="inbound.behavior">listening</parameter>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="port">5000</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

The request sequence that connected to that inbound is:

```
sequence name="request" statistics="enable" trace="enable">
    <in>
        <log level="full"/>
        <send/>
    </in>
    <out>
        <send/>
    </out>
</sequence>
```

My problem is: when I sending ISO8583 message from java client to that inbound port, there is no reply to the client, also nothing is showing up in the service bus system log!

Kindly any suggestion will be useful.

Thank you!

Comment: HI, Did you test with ISO8583 connector?

Comment: Hi Rajjaz, thank you for your answer i tried to send a message from the connector, but the connector have a problem too! i implement it latterly as mentioned in the documentation but it shows me the error " Couldn't packed ISO8583 Messages" when try to send XML message through the proxy service. appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you try with the below message from your client
0200B2200000001000000000000000800000201234000000010000011072218012345606A5DFGR021ABCDEFGHIJ 1234567890

Comment: Thank you Rajjaz, i am still not having any entry in the System log.

Comment: Can you please share with me the write log configuration you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the relevant jars and put it into the /repository/components/lib directory as mentioned in the Documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+ISO8583+Inbound+Operations and try with following request sequence to connect the inbound.

```
<sequence name="request" onError="fault">
    <log level="full"/>
```

You can test the inbound with any simple java client programme. (For an example refer the link : https://github.com/Kanapriya/ISO8583TestClient)
Remember that that the messages need to be in ISO8583 standard.

Comment: Dear Priya, I already did the jars part, the client you mentioned is working perfectly and i got a response from server, still there is no log entry in the ESB system log, please can you advice about that?